# Interpolation to match dataset size in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, interpolation

If I have two datasets with different sizes for example:

```
x1 = [0,2,5,10,12,20,15,14] #length = 8
y1 = [0,0.3,0.6,1.1,1.3,2.1,1.6,1.5] #length = 8

x2 = [0,2,4,5,10,12,13,20,18,15,14] #length = 11
y2 = [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,1.1,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.6,1.9,1.8] #length = 11
```

How can I get the x1,y1 dataset to grow in size to match the x2,y2 dataset length of 11? But still somewhat have the correct value e.g. like interpolation between the diffrences to fill the gaps.

The question is answered in python but I need it in javascript. [Orignal python question if found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123124/interpolation-to-match-dataset-size).

Comment: Question answered in javascript too?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941168/javascript-interpolate-an-array-of-numbers  Also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/cubic-spline

Comment: Which kind of interpolation are you looking for? Linear?

Comment: Yes linear interpolation.

Comment: @James you are right. Thanks! I have search all over for that one.